# sys.path does not automatically include the current working directory

Tags: python, sys

I use the python.org installer on Win 10.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) say that, when running a script from the command line, the first item in `sys.path` will be the path to the script. I always see that. These docs do not say that the second item will be the directory from which the script is run, but in years of using Python I have always seen this behavior, and others refer to it as well.  The docs say that `sys.path` is "initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default." I would like to understand what that phrase means.  For example, if PYTHONPATH is empty (PowerShell: `$env:PYTHONPATH = ""`), then to my surprise this second item is not added. Otoh, if PYTHONPATH starts with a semicolon (PowerShell: `$env:PYTHONPATH = ";"`), then this second item is added.

I suppose that this must be the expected behavior?  I am looking for i. confirmation of this supposition, and ii. and explanation of what I am seeing (as described at the end of the previous paragraph).  My guess is that a PYTHONPATH of ";" is considered to start with an empty string, and that this causes the inclusion of the working directory.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but `os.path.abspath("")` gives you the current directory.

Comment: `the second item will be the directory from which the script is run`, is this true ?

Comment: @Philippe Under the exact conditions that I describe in the question, that is what I am seeing (on multiple Windows 10 systems).